# How to uninstall IIS on windows 8.1 so I can XAMPP on port 80

Tags: iis, xampp, windows-8.1

I installed IIS on my Windows 8.1 computer but now I want to work with XAMPP. At first I got this error:

```
Problem detected!
9:32:40 PM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
9:32:40 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
9:32:40 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
9:32:40 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I deleted IIS from control panel and unchecked IIS from *"Turn Windows features on and off"* then I restarted.

But yet when I type `localhost` in my browser IIS comes up and doesn't let me use XAMPP as my localhost in my project. When I choose XAMPP for my project and run it then I see error 404 because it can't define XAMPP as my localhost.

I want to work with XAMPP, what should I do?

Comment: An easy option would be to move apache to a port that isn't 80.

Comment: as i said i did so i changeed the port and XAMPP start but my project can't come on with XAMPP... @WyattBarnett

Answer (score 1):

If you unchecked IIS (and all the child nodes) from the "Windows Features" then IIS is gone, so you might have another process using that port. Historically many applications have decided to use that (chats, music players, and others).

I would run netstat as below to find all the processes that are listening/using TCP port 80 and using the PID find in Task Manager who they are:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :80
```

There find the PID (last column) and find the culprit. If it is SYSTEM (usually PID 4, and reading your question, that is likely the case, so keep reading) , then some application is using HTTP.sys to listen in Port 80. So for that you'll need to then look in HTTP.sys, for that:

```
netsh http show servicestate > out.txt
notepad out.txt
```

there you can find the registered URLs by searching for ":80/" and see if that gives you a clue of who is doing that.